# Use one SQL statement to update all rows of a single column with respective pieces of data

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 10 rows which contains a column named "age" and holds int(3). Is there a way to update all the rows with everyone's respective ages with one SQL statement?

I've been doing

```
update table_name set age = age_int where first_name = "John";
```

over and over again. But I'm wondering if I can condense all 10 statements into one.

Comment: Is the age for all the rows are same?

Comment: no. everyone is a different age.

Comment: If you don't have these ages in a table somewhere, then you don't really have a choice; you have to do separate update statements.

Comment: Note that the number in parentheses following the INT is almost meaningless - and storing the age of a (living) person is a fairly daft idea.

Comment: okay. that's what I thought, but my teacher posed the question is such a way that made it seem like I should be using just one statement. So I got confused.

Comment: Is `age_int` a column in that table that has the correct age per record ? Or is your SQL just an example where you change the age_int to a number? Or does that table have some column from which to derive the age, f.e. `birth_date` ?

Comment: oh. sorry about that. the only columns in the table are "first_name", "last_name", and "age." I put age_int in the example as a variable. So it would actually be a number that I type in.

Comment: That's fine. But just FYI, from what I've seen in most databases they just keep the birth date in such table, and then calculate the age from that when they select from it.  That way the table doesn't need to be updated all the time to correct the ages.  But then again, this is just some challenge from your teacher.

Comment: Where exactly do the ages come from? You could simply increment age by 1 on a particular date every year, that will make sure that ages are somewhat accurate. May be that is what they wanted.

Comment: Btw, are those first_name unique? Or aren't they unique and should the last_name also be considered for the update?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `case` expression:

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET age = CASE first_name 
       WHEN 'abc' THEN 10
       WHEN 'xyz' THEN 11
END
```

Comment: I typed that in and it didn't work. I'm really new to SQL, so I'm not sure what a case statement is or what it might be missing.